# How to turn off or disable the middle (scroll) button's light on my mouse?

Tags: mouse, scrolling, led, mouse-buttons, canyon

I just bought a new Canyon optical mouse, but the middle button (scroll button) has a blue light. It distracts me. Is there a way to turn it off or disable it?

Comment: What is the exact model of the Mouse?

Comment: It's Canyon wired optical mouse, CNR-MSO01N.

Answer (score 2):

For your Mouse CNR-MSO01N is no Utility/driver available to disable the LED. you can open the mouse and sever the wired connection to the LED but that will void the warranty.

Comment: That makes me very VERY pissed. I just wasted my money on this stupid mouse. They should put a label with big capital letters on the mouse saying it has a LED scroll.

Comment: there is a big label stating just that on their homepage. [Link](https://imgur.com/a/WSpeytn)

Comment: I bought it from the tech store, not their website. I would never buy anything from canyon again.

Comment: @TaishoMori that is not Canyon's fault. It probably says on the box that it has an LED scroll wheel. They probably have other mice that don't have LED's. You're overreacting to say the least.

Comment: No, it doesn't say anywhere on the box that the scroll button is blue LED. It pisses me off because i needed a mice and i didn't even had time to shop, but now i have to go back there again to return it or buy another one. They just wasted my time, and why would anyone even wanna buy a mice with button that keeps glowing like a lamp?

Comment: @TaishoMori "i didn't even had time to shop" This is why you should research before you buy. It's ok though just return it but for your replacement make sure you learned your lesson, research the features it comes with, then buy.

Answer (score 0):

You can set rgb(0 0 0) color in mouse software next to dpi field. It will turn the wheel lights off

Comment: Please give clearer instructions.